# Crystal Report will not load

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm getting a very arbitrary error when trying to load a crystal report.

The error is:

```
    "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The document has not been opened.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException",
    "StackTrace": "   at 
       CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.get_ReportAppServer()\r\n   
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.get_ReportAppServer()\r\n   at 
       CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()"
}
```

I googled this and many say that it is a security issue, So I've added the App pool, IUSR, and I went as far as adding Everyone to the folder. That did not work.

I Installed Visual Studio on the server and was able to run the report in Visual Studio it runs there, but when I try `report.Load(reportPath);` it throws this error.

So I started thinking it must be something with the path I hardcoded the path `"C:/Reports/Report.rpt"` that still gave the same error.

Please let me know if there you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. I had to uninstall crystal reports and reinstall it.